# Phonegap Build app not showing splashscreen for Iphone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I have built a Phonegap Build app and run into a bit of a bug. I've created all the appropriate images and referenced them in my config.xml file.

However for some reason they are not showing in iPhone 6, 6s or 6+. All other sizes seem to show the splashscreen without any issues. here's my code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id          = "com.myapp.app.com.app.myapp"
        versionCode = "10" 
        version     = "1.0.8"
        ios-CFBundleVersion="1.0.17" >

<!-- versionCode is optional and Android only -->

<name>My App</name>

<description>
   My App
</description>

<author href="http://www.myemail.co.uk"" email="chris@myemail.co.uk">
    Chris Burns
</author>

<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

<!-- iOS -->

    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="app/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 / 6+ -->
    <icon src="app/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="app/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="app/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="app/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="app/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="app/img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

    <icon src="app/img/icons/apple-touch-icon.png" />

<!-- -->

<platform name="ios">

    <!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
    <splash src="app/img/splash/320x480.png" platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <splash src="app/img/splash/640x960.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

    <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <splash src="app/img/splash/640x1136.png" platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

    <!-- iPhone 6 -->
    <splash src="app/img/splash/750x1334.png" platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="app/img/splash/1242x2208.png" platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <splash src="app/img/splash/2208x1242.png" platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

    <!-- iPhone 6S -->
    <splash src="app/img/splash/1080x1920.png" platform="ios" width="1080" height="1920" />

    <!-- iPad -->
    <splash src="app/img/splash/768x1024.png" platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <splash src="app/img/splash/1024x768.png" platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

    <!-- Retina iPad -->
    <splash src="app/img/splash/1536x2048.png" platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <splash src="app/img/splash/2048x1536.png" platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

</platform>

<platform name="android" />

<splash src="splash.png" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="3.2.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.2" />
```

Comment: Do the PGB standard. Erase from the server, re-upload and try again. It works almost all of the the time. I can't see anything obviously wrong with the code.

Comment: Have the same strange problem. On iPhone6 it shows default Cordova splashscreen!

Comment: Hi is there any update on this one? I have the same issue as well.

Comment: Me too.. any update? did you fix it?

Comment: Still no update I'm afraid

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect